# problems when unioning and dissolving polygons in R

Tags: r, gis, polygons

Sometimes, when working with SpatialPolygons in R with the sp and rgeos packages, I run into problems when subsetting and dissolving these polygons. 
This example shows the types of problems I have had, though I've had it happen with other datasets too.

```
require(maptools)
require(rgeos)

data(wrld_simpl)

countries <- c("Argentina","Bolivia","Brazil","Chile","Colombia","Ecuador","Guyana","Paraguay","Peru","Suriname","Uruguay","Venezuela")
SAmerica <- subset(wrld_simpl,wrld_simpl@data$NAME == countries[1])

for (i in 2:length(countries)) {
    x <- subset(wrld_simpl, wrld_simpl@data$NAME == countries[i])
    SAmerica <- gUnion(SAmerica, x)
}

plot(SAmerica)
gIsValid(SAmerica)

shoreline <- gUnaryUnion(SAmerica)
plot(shoreline)
```

[image]

There are visible line segments in the areas where the polygons border each other, and this unioned polygon is not valid in the rgeos package.

I am curious about (1) why this is happening?, and (2) what the best way to fix such problems is. Here, I could definitely find better data for country vector files, but sometimes I might be working with more unique data. How can I clean this up?

Comment: This is a poor data, suffering from topology errors, a lot of mismatches, resulting from the data quality. You can check it in a GIS with topology tools

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that wrld_simpl is a poor dataset. It should be replaced by a better data, with no topological errors.

A Manifold GIS view of detected errors in wrld_simpl dataset

[image: manifold GIS]

You can try your approach with a better data and the result will be much better.

```
countries <- c("Bolivia","Brazil","Chile","Colombia","Ecuador","Guyana",
               "Paraguay","Peru","Suriname","Uruguay","Venezuela")

writeOGR(wrld_simpl, dsn = 'd:', layer = 'wrld_simpl', driver = 'ESRI Shapefile' )
# Correct topology (normalize topology with Manifol GIS
# reducing precision to 0.00001
```

Download topology normalized data from [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rd81lbj62dhd9rz/samerica_norm.zip)

```
sam_topo <- readOGR(dsn = 'd:/', layer = 'Samerica')

#plot(sam_topo, axes = T)
sam2 <- sam_topo[sam_topo$NAME == "Argentina", ]

for (i in countries) {
  x <- sam_topo[sam_topo$NAME == i,]
  sam2 <- gUnion(sam2, x)
}

gIsValid(sam2)
shoreline <- gUnaryUnion(sam2)
plot(shoreline)
```

[image: shoreline]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way to do this using `getData(...)` in the `raster` package. This avoids the use of `for` loops and external software.

```
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
world     <- getData("countries")
countries <- c("Argentina","Bolivia","Brazil","Chile","Colombia","Ecuador","Guyana","Paraguay","Peru","Suriname","Uruguay","Venezuela")
SAmerica  <- gUnaryUnion(world[world$ENGLISH %in% countries,])
plot(SAmerica)
gIsValid(SAmerica)
# [1] TRUE
```

[image]

The world database loaded by `getData(...)` also has a `CONTINENTS` field in the attributes table, in this specific case you could achieve the exact same result using:

```
SAmerica  <- gUnaryUnion(world[world$CONTINENT=="South America",])
```

Comment: True! This is a much better data set.

Comment: That's a good point, I had forgotten about that dataset. And I suppose there are no convenient geometry repair tools in R? My question here is also how to deal with bad polygon data in R...