# Dissolved polygons using R not plotting correctly

Tags: r, gis, polygon

I'm trying to perform a dissolve in R. I've previously done this in QGIS but I want to achieve this in R to integrate with the rest of my workflow if possible.

I have an ESRI shapefile with small geographical polygons (output areas, if you're familiar with UK census geography). I also have a lookup table provided to me with a list of all OA codes with their associated aggregated geography code.

I can't provide the actual files I'm working on, but comparable files and a minimal reproducable example below:

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/4puoof8u5btigxq/oa-soa.csv?dl=1 (130kb csv)
- https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqbi7ub2122q14r/soa.zip?dl=1 (~4MB shp)

And code:

```
require("rgdal")  # for readOGR
require("rgeos")  # for gUnion
require("maptools")

unzip("soa.zip")
soa <- readOGR(dsn = "soa", "england_oac_2011")
proj4string(soa) <- CRS("+init=epsg:27700")  # British National Grid

lookup <- read.csv("oa-soa.csv")

slsoa <- gUnaryUnion(soa, id = lookup$LSOA11CD)
```

I've also tried:

```
slsoa <- unionSpatialPolygons(soa, lookup$$LSOA11CD)
```

but my understanding is that since I have (R)GEOS installed this uses the gUnion methods from the rgeos package anyway.

So, my problem is that the dissolve appears to work; I don't get an error message and the length() function suggests I now have fewer polygons:

```
length(soa@polygons)    # 1,817
length(slsoa@polygons)  # should be 338
```

but the plots appear to be the same (i.e. the internal dissolves haven't worked), as demonstrated by the following two plots:

```
plot(soa)
plot(slsoa)
```

I've looked around on the internet and stackoverflow to see if I can solve my issue and found several articles but without success.

- [problems when unioning and dissolving polygons in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764169/problems-when-unioning-and-dissolving-polygons-in-r) (I don't think the quality of the shapefile is the problem because I'm using a lookup table to match geographies).
- https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/PolygonDissolveOperationsR (uses two sp objects, not lookup table).
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93441/problem-with-merging-and-dissolving-a-shapefile-in-r (as far as I can tell I've followed the relevant steps)

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong and why the plots aren't working correctly?

Thanks muchly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your `soa` shapefile has 1817 elements, each with a unique `code` (corresponding to `lookup$OA11CD`). But your `lookup` file has only 1667 rows. Obviously, `lookup` **does not** have "a list of all OA codes".

Second, unless `lookup` has the same codes as your shapefile **in the same order**, using `gUnaryUnion(...)` this way will yield garbage. You need to merge `soa@data` with `lookup` on the corresponding fields first.

Third, `gUnaryUnion(...)` cannot remove internal boundaries if the polygons are not contiguous (obviously).

This seems to work

```
soa   <- merge(soa,lookup,by.x="code",by.y="OA11CD",all.x=TRUE)
slsoa <- gUnaryUnion(soa,id=soa$LSOA11CD)
length(slsoa)
# [1] 338
par(mfrow=c(1,2),mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(soa);plot(slsoa)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I knew I was missing something fairly obvious. This worked both on the reproducable example and on the data I was working on. The lengths of soa/lookup are interesting. I hadn't noticed that and they're downloaded straight from the Office of National Statistics, so they should match! Thanks.